# Apex Generation Failed (WSDL parsing error)

Tags: webservices, parsing

I'm trying to parse a simple Webservice and I'm receiving this error:

> Apex Generation Failed:
>
> Unable to find complexType for {http://soap.***}RelationshipReferenceTo

There are two lines in the WSDL file with the `RelationshipReferenceTo`:

```
<xsd:complexType name="EntityParticle">
<xsd:element name="ReferenceTo" minOccurs="0" type="tns:RelationshipReferenceTo" nillable="true"/>
```

And

```
<xsd:complexType name="FieldDefinition">
<xsd:element name="ReferenceTo" minOccurs="0" type="tns:RelationshipReferenceTo" nillable="true"/>
```

Can anyone help to solve this problem and allow me to parse this XML file?